# Adding custom/extension attribute to shipping/billing address :: js set-shipping-infromation-mixin.js error

Tags: magento2

Magento 2.3.1

I referred to the following link for adding a custom/extension attribute to the shipping address

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html

However, when I pressed 'next' to go Review & Payments step in checkout stage I get the following error

[image]

Comment: Post error messages as **text**. FYI there's also https://magento.stackexchange.com/